# Select record by group and condition using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains customer names. Customers can have multiple names (i.e. multiple records tied to the same customer ID) and these names can be different names types (i.e. legal, preferred, etc.). I'd like to select the preferred name when present and the legal name when there is no preferred name. But I am not too sure the best way of going about this.

Here is the example table:

| ID | TYPE | FIRST | LAST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PREF | Johnny | Smith |
| 1 | LEGAL | John | Smith |
| 2 | PREF | Sophia | Apple |
| 3 | LEGAL | Tim | Ritter |

And here is the desired outcome:

| ID | TYPE | FIRST | LAST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PREF | Johnny | Smith |
| 2 | PREF | Sophia | Apple |
| 3 | LEGAL | Tim | Ritter |

Answer (score 1):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by type desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where type in ('PREF', 'LEGAL')
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or, if there is at most one of each type of name, then you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type = 'PREF' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.type = 'LEGAL'
                 );
```